# Execute XHR from HTML-Document

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to test my XHR in HTML with the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> testing </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
                <script lang="JavaScript">
        var clientID = "abc";
        var secret = "def";
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.withCredentials = true;       
        oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        document.write("Going to make a call");

        //OAuthAccessor.clientID, OAuthAccessor.secret

        oReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
            //console.log
            document.write("state changed - new state: " + oReq.readyState + " and Status: " + oReq.status);
            if (oReq.readyState === 4) {
                if (oReq.status === 200) {
                    //console.log
                    document.write(oReq.responseText);
                } else { 
                    //console.log
                    document.write("Error: " + oReq.status + " Message: " + oReq.responseText);
                } 
            }    
        };
        //console.log
        document.write("Status: " + oReq.status);
        oReq.open("POST", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", true, clientID, secret);
        oReq.send(); 
        //console.log
        document.write("Request send");

        </script>  
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not getting anything written down on my document - what's wrong with that code? When executing it from an emulator it works.

Comment: are you trying to do it from localhost?

Comment: debugging 101 - open the browser **developer** tools console and check for warnings/errors/messages that may indicate the source of the issue

Comment: via file:///path-to-file - he changed the title successfully, so he should find that document and execute it.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, I will have a look at it. Outcome:
He has an "InvalidStateError" for the xhr when calling    `oReq.withCredentials = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the Console in your browser's developer tools.
2. Read the error message

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.

Changing the order of the code so it reads:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", true, clientID, secret);
```

… fixes the problem.

**Always read your error messages**.